# Excel's Solver does not understand the constraints

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

I have an integer programming problem that I formulated in excel. My problem is as below and I do not know what is wrong:

For example we have $30$ hours of available time. It takes $2$ hours to assembly a phone, $4$ hours for a PC and $3$ hours for a TV. After adding all such constraints, I want to maximize total profit. The solver can not find  a convergent solution. However, if I say set objective value  to $1000$ dollars when profit per a phone is $25$ dollars for example, it finds a solution like  $40$-many phones and none of any other product. The problem is, that should not be possible since it will take $40\times2 = 80$ hours of assembly time.

What may be the problem? I am out of ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Are all of your constraints consistent? Have you typed them in with the inequalities the right way round so that a feasible region exists? Your second issue may not be a problem - it could be that time is not a binding constraint. Impossible to say anything more without seeing your problem.

Comment: It's also possible that your formulation is correct but you fed it to Solver incorrectly.